# Not able to cover batch class which is deleting expired content document

Tags: unit-test, contentdocument

I am writing test class for batch class which will delete all the content documents which are expired.

And I am getting this error "System.SerializationException: Not Serializable: com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Database/DeleteResult$$r"

what could be the reason for this error and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 4):

A batchable that is marked with [Database.Stateful](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) must only use class fields that are [serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization) such as primitive data types and collections of them. (`DeleteResult`  is not serializable.) Most data in a batchable need not be kept in a field and can be kept in a local variable inside e.g. the `execute` method.

I don't know why you are only seeing this error in your test; not keeping hold of the `DeleteResult` data in a class field is a likely solution. If you are keeping hold of those for error reporting purposes, build the error string and keep a list of those instead in a class field.

**PS**

The current code may look something like this:

```
public class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<Contact>, Database.Stateful {

    private List<DeleteResult> results;

    public MyBatchable() {
        results = new List<DeleteResult>();
    }

    // start

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> scope) {
         Database.DeleteResult[] scopeResults = Database.delete(scope, false);
         results.addAll(scopeResults);
    }

    // finish that will e.g. send an email summarising all results
}
```

and I'm suggesting it should look more like this:

```
public class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<Contact>, Database.Stateful {

    private List<String> results;

    public MyBatchable() {
        results = new List<String>();
    }

    // start

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> scope) {
         Database.DeleteResult[] scopeResults = Database.delete(scope, false);
         for (Database.DeleteResult r : scopeResults) {
             // Check isSuccess and getErrors values and build result string
             String text = ...
             results.addAll(text);
         }
    }

    // finish that will e.g. send an email summarising all results
}
```

Comment: I am using DeleteResult in my batch class,but I am not sure about the workaround you explained.
Can you explain with an example.Thanks!

Comment: @devsfdc I've added an outline of the difference to the answer in a PS.